# Phonegap error with xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cordova, cors

I'm just trying to get login page for my app with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loa").load("http://www.agroagro.com/login.php");
});
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.agroagro.com/login.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://agroagro.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

The problem is when I have only .load(login.php) everything works fine but when I type .load(agroagro.com/login.php) I get error from above, so becouse i want to use phonegap to build native app i need to have full url address?

Any idea how to solve this?

Also one more question - Is better way like I do load .php file via JQ or is better to make a AJAX call to php file ?

For me its easier to make a load .php file becouse I have code there where I'm not using ajax.

What about performance - load .php or make ajax call ?

Comment: Do you test on device or browser

Comment: Test in device, it will working. If you want request working in browser then request must be same domain with server, or server side must supported CORS

Answer (score 1):

The Browsers do not allow us to make call to other domains unless or otherwise we have had the allow request from where we are requestion or for all other domains

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Use the above line in the `http://www.agroagro.com/login.php` page

Hope it works

Comment: have you uploaded that to server?

Comment: maybe is probem becouse in login page I have many other resources (includes menu.php , init.php and similar ) ?

Comment: @user827341 Are you sure you dont have some cache serving an old version of the page, because i dont see that header being sent: http://i.imgur.com/PthvumA.png

Comment: I will see now... also after login I must be redirected to index.php page, how I can do that?

Comment: you use phonegap rite? It uses basic javascript? It better you design pages here and call for an api like thing to do authentication or get data from DB or Send data to DB. And phone gap is designed in such a manner

Comment: is there some tutorial which will explain step by step how to make user login, register that work with phonegap

Comment: have you created basic project structure?

Comment: This answer is essentially correct, user827341, but since it is not working for you (the posted snippet is php, not javascript) then you should research CORS for your situation, that is; Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. Make sure your httpd server for www.agroagro.com is not denying Cross-Origin requests, for starters. I'm positive the above answer is on the right track.

Comment: Now works fine: http://agroagro.com/template/tema/wrap.html but I cant login with username:mile and pass:asdasd ... why? That cant me  redirect to index.php when I login in?